# Crontab Job Won't Run Python Script at Reboot

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, cron

When running a `python` script manually from terminal, the script runs successfully.

When scheduled with `crontab -e` with the following entry:

`@reboot export DISPLAY=:0 sudo /bin/sleep 60 && gnome-terminal -e 'sudo python3 /path/to/script/script.py'`

The script fails.  Reports a `connection refused` message.

The script imports `selenium` and relies on the `Firefox` webdriver to navigate through websites in a kiosk-like display.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:** When I schedule the script with `crontab`, the following error is printed in the terminal:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/pi/Desktop/photo_frames/becky/get_urls.py", line 19, in <module>    
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist- 
packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 150, in __init__keep_alive=True)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist- 
packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 92, in __init__
self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist- 
packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 179, in start_session
response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, capabilities)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist- 
packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 236, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist- 
packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 192, in 
check_response raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: connection refused
```

Comment: What is the exact command that works successfully from the terminal?

Comment: Have you tried running `gnome-terminal -e 'sudo python3 /path/to/script/script.py'` from a terminal?

Comment: I have, it opens a new instance of `gnome-terminal` and executes the `python` script.

Comment: Is a 60 second sleep after bootup long enough?  Maybe there's some service the python script needs that hasn't started up yet?

Comment: Worth a shot - I'm going to try a longer sleep and report back.

Comment: Does the python script say which connection was refused?

Comment: Error is too long to post as a comment, here is a `gist.github.com` 

https://gist.github.com/dcstrassburger/6fdd94f7ac50fade56d35df38e12dcea

Comment: @Daniel You should edit it into the question.